# How to add multiple views inside SwipeRefreshLayout, with one of them being recyclerview?

Tags: android, xml

I have a recyclerview inside SwipeRefreshLayout. and at the end of recyclerview, I'd like to add a button, but I'm unable to do so. Here the code :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/refresh"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:paddingBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/load_more"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="@color/md_black_1000"
        android:text="TEST"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

The button does not appear at the end of the recyclerview.

Answer (score 11):

> SwipeRefreshLayout could have only one child.

Add `RecyclerView` and `Button` to vertical `LinearLayout` and put it into `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        <Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

To add `Button` as last item in `RecyclerView` you need edit `adapter`:

1) increase number of rows

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return pictureArrayList.size() + 1;
}
```

2) show `Button` when list ends

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ExampleHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Picture picture = pictureArrayList.get(position);
    if (position <= pictureArrayList.size()) {
        holder.title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.title.setText(picture.getName());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(picture.getImage());
    } else {
        holder.title.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want it at the end of Recyclerview. That is, once the recyclerview has been fully scrolled. This doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a RecyclerView with different view items depending on what you want to do may be an option to use a view button at the bottom of the list, I have a blog post where I wrote a blog about the RecyclerView(Spanish).

http://erikcaffrey.github.io/2015/10/05/recyclerview/

You can see the code!

https://github.com/erikcaffrey/RecyclerView-Examples

Comment: Could you point me the example that shows this? The one you has posted has multiple examples

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_aprovacao_pedido_list_swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_aprovacao_pedido_list_empty_ll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/activity_aprovacao_pedido_list_app_compact_image_view_empty"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp_5"
                android:padding="@dimen/dp_10" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/activity_aprovacao_pedido_list_app_compat_text_view_empty"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/default_hifen"
                android:textColor="@color/black_alpha73"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp_16"
                android:visibility="visible" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/activity_aprovacao_pedido_list_recycler_view_pedido"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Here's my example of an empty list status